# VirtualBox installation of CentOS boots into text terminal

Tags: centos, virtualbox, system-installation

This is my first time setting up a VirtualBox machine on macOS, and I don't understand if I got something wrong, but when I'm booting my CentOS VM I'm only running into a kernel terminal interface although my goal is for a graphical interface. Anyone got an idea?[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you see whon you boot the machine? Is there a login prompt, and can you log in? Or are you presented with a kernel panic? What packages were installed during installation. I'm not familiar with the installation process of CentOS, but I'm assuming that it asks you about what sets of packages to install and possibly also what graphical desktop to use. Did this happen at all. Have you tried to re-do the installation (which would be trivial on a virtual system)?

Comment: I assume that by `kernel terminal interface` you mean the Linux virtual console (possible you did not install any desktop environment and you are in multi-user mode). Or maybe, by kernel terminal interface you meant you are in a screen with some error (maybe grub or some error at booting). Please provide an actual screenshot about what are you getting when you boot.

Comment: thank you both for the reply, it must be the desktop environment not selected at the beginning as the reason. Even though at the mentioned terminal I did set it as "systemctl set-default graphical.target" since it was at multi-user.target but it did not work when I rebooted it. Nonetheless, I am reinstalling from the beginning and this time I choose the desktop environment and will update you after it is done.

Comment: I must note, additionally at the initiation of the virtual machine a error output as follows: Failed to run unattended guest installation.
Unknown guest OS major version '7'.
Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)
Component:
UnattendedWrap
Interface:
IUnattended {6f89464f-7773-436a-a4df-592e4e537fa0}

Comment: The distro just finished installing and it is working, ultimately it was choosing the desktop environment at initiation. Thanks for the help, and you may close the question!